# Django ManyToManyField Creation Problems

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I currently have these models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='child')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True, related_name='tag_item')
```

My issue is, I can't add tags to any Items that I've already created. If I attempt to do something like:

```
>>> cat = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> cat.tag_item.create(item_id = 1)
```

I get `TypeError: 'item_id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

However, if I do:

```
>>> cat.tag_item.create()
```

I end up with a newly created empty item.

I also don't understand how I would perform a query to get all tags for a particular item? There is no Tag class because I don't have to specify a `through` attribute on the ManyToManyField since there is no extra data, so I can't use a Tag manager to do something like `Tag.objects.filter(item_id=3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at some examples [here](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/).

Basically, you should do:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
```

To create an item, a tag and associate them, do the following:

```
item = Item(name='test')
item.save()
tag = Category(name='foo')
item.tags.add(tag)
```

and to query all tags:

```
item.tags.all()
```